# Cannot Store Data into ArrayLists?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, do-while

thanks for all the help guys but now the nature of the question has changed using Patrick's suggestion below loop is running but it dise not seem to be storing the input to respective arrays data keeps hetting replaced into the ArrayLists rather than going to the next position into the ArrayList any suggestions?

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrray {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList<String> names;
        ArrayList<String> addr;


        do {
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
            addr = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Name and Adreess are: " + names.size() + "**"
                    + addr.size());
            System.out.println("please Enter Your Name :");
            names.add(userInput.next());
            System.out.println("please enter your Address  :");
            addr.add(userInput.next());

            System.out.println("Do you want to add another entry? :(y/n)" );
            String ans =userInput.next();  // get the value from the user using scanner class
            if(ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N"))
                break;

        } while (true);
        int n = names.size();
        int a = addr.size();
        for(int i =0; i<n && i<a; i++ )
            System.out.println("Name and address are as below:  "+ names.get(i)+"**"+ addr.get(i));




    }

}
```

Comment: what have you tried? (false) as a loop condition will never re-run you loop. And where do you actually try to get the user input for the (y/n) choice? Would be nice to see at least a little effort before posting here

Comment: and you are recreating list for each user so it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: guys very very new to java as in starting last week new so forgive the ignorance and no its not homework just trying to learn to work with array lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get value from the user and if user enter n then break otherwise nothing

```
System.out.println("Do you want to add another entry? :(y/n)" );
String ans = .... // get the value from the user using scanner class
if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
     break;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Patrick appreciate the help. it is running the loop again but it dose not seem to be storing the data into arrays it keeps replacing it with the new entry what i am trying to get at is to fill the both ArrayLists any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while(true)` in conjunction with a [break statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#break_statement):

```
do {
    if(input.next() == 'n'){
        break;
    }
} while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture this user's input

```
System.out.println("Do you want to add another entry? :(y/n)");
```

and use that info in the while.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
String choice = "";
do {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    System.out.println("Do you want to add another entry? :(y/n)" );
    choice = userInput.next();
} while (!(choice.equals("n") || choice.equals("N")));
```

The line

```
choice = userInput.next();
```

will read user input, and the  `String` classes `equals` method for comparing the input. The loop will continue until the choice is either `N` or `n`.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        name.add(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
        phone.add(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Do you want to add a directory y/n?");
        answer = scanner.next();
    } while (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"));
    if (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y")); //want it to go back to start another direcotry here
    else {
        System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the directory");
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(name.get(i) + "\t");
            System.out.print(phone.get(i));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

}